# How to create a single instance of a helper class inside my base page model

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, inheritance

I am trying to create a single instance of my calendar picker helper class in my base page model so that all of my other page models that inherit from base page will be able to use that instance of calendar picker helper.

Here is my helper class

```
class CalendarHelper : BasePage
{
    public CalendarHelper(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my base page model

```
class BasePage
{
    public IWebDriver Driver;
    public CalendarHelper Calendar;
 
    public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        Driver = driver;
        Calendar = new CalendarHelper(driver);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is a continuous loop when instantiating Calendar, because of the passing in the driver and then it calling base page again. Is there a way I can setup this single instance of Calendar so that all my other page models that inherit from BasePage can use it? Also want Calendar to be able to use all the methods within BasePage.

Comment: you could just put the methods inside of BasePage.  Driver is available there.  You could also do like you are doing now, but remove " : BasePage" from the Calendar class.  You don't need it since you are making a reference to Calendar in BasePage already.  Any class which extends BasePage will have Calendar available, too.

Comment: I recommend to introduce dependency injection and register the helper class as singleton.

Comment: Isn't this the reason why static was invented?

Answer (score 0):

Helpers should not be part of BasePage. Helpers should be something like a wrapper for your page logic, for loops and adding other logics related to pages.
If your application has calendar in SomePage, it should called CalendarComponent and it should exists on your OrderPage as component.

For example

```
public class SomePage : BasePage
{
    public readonly CalendarComponent CalendarComponent;

    public SomePage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    //Elements and methods for this page...
}

public class CalendarComponent : BaseComponent
{
    public CalendarComponent(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    //logic for calendar component...it could be reusable in other pages!

    public void TypeCalendarName(string calendarName) => Driver.FindElement(locator).SendKeys(calendarName);
}

public static class CalendarHelper
{
    public static void TypeCalendarNames(CalendarComponent calendarComponent, params string[] calendarNames)
    {
        calendarNames.ToList().ForEach(calendarName => calendarComponent.TypeCalendarName(calendarName) //+ other logic...
    }
}
```

And to use it in a test:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void SetCalendarNames()
    {
        string[] calendarNames = { "firstname", "secondname" };

        var somePage = new SomePage(Driver);

        CalendarHelper.TypeCalendarNames(somePage.CalendarComponent, calendarNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: The important part about this answer is to break the circular dependency between CalendarHelper and BasePage. I'm a little confused why you wouldn't add `TypeCalendarNames` as an instance method of CalendarComponent. Why separate them?

Comment: I agree, but I have given only easy example for helper. Method TypeCalendarNames() could be also in component, but pages and components in my opinion should include only basic implementation and treat it like low level, helpers are like wrappers in higher level. BasePage should includes only components as aggregation without helpers. Helpers are usefull directly in your test methods. I guess you treat CalendarHelper as CalendarComponent?

Comment: Basically yes. In general, helper methods and classes can become a dumping ground for behavior. Given the example, it seemed perfectly fine to put the method in the component, however I don't think you can make this an unbreakable rule. It is very situational.

Answer (score 0):

There is a circular dependency between BasePage and CalendarHelper, which explains the problem. I see a few solutions:

1. **Break the circular dependency.** This should be the one you implement, but without seeing the code in CalendarHelper it is difficult to know if this will be a good solution. Simply do not inherit from BasePage in CalendarHelper.
2. **Initialize CalendarHelper in the page models that need it.** This is what I typically do. Analyze the page models that *actually* need a CalendarHelper, and initialize it in those classes. Yes, it means you are initializing this object more than once, but unless you find a measurable performance problem, don't worry about it. Here the goal is modular and reusable code, not preventing code repetition.
3. **Add a static property to BasePage.**

   This would be my least preferable solution, since this eliminates the ability to run tests concurrently. The `driver` object would be shared between concurrent running tests, which will cause the tests to fail. The first concrete class to call the BasePage constructor is the one that creates this shared helper object.

   ```
   class BasePage
   {
       private static CalendarHelper sharedCalendarHelper;

       public IWebDriver Driver;
       public CalendarHelper Calendar => sharedCalendarHelper;

       public BasePage(IWebDriver driver)
       {
           Driver = driver;
           sharedCalendarHelper ||= new CalendarHelper(driver);
       }
   }
   ```